# Help with asymptotic expansion to a serie

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

using:
$$\varepsilon_n(x) = \displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{t^{n}}dt$$
with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. If $e_1 = \frac{1}{2};e_2=\frac{1}{8};e_3=\frac{-1}{32};e_4=\frac{-1}{128}.$

Show that: 
$$\varepsilon_{n}(x)\sim e^{-x}\displaystyle \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \frac{e_s}{x^s} $$
if $x \to \infty.$
I think on doing induction over $n$, but I have trouble doing this, I would be very grateful if you can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Use integration by parts or Watson's lemma. Also, your coefficients $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ are incorrect.

Comment: Jmm ok, but how are the coefficients then?

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple methods to obtain the asymptotic series.

### Option 1

The first option is to use repeated integration by parts. In the formula

$$
\int_1^\infty u\,dv = uv\Bigr|_{1}^{\infty} - \int_1^\infty v\,du,
$$

take $u = t^{-n}$ and $dv = e^{-xt}{dt}$. Then repeat this on the new integral using the same pattern. Do this four times to calculate the first four coefficients $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$.

### Option 2

Make the substitution $t = s+1$ in the integral to get

$$
\int_1^\infty e^{-xt}t^{-n} \,dt = e^{-x}\int_0^\infty e^{-xs}(s+1)^{-n} \,ds.
$$

This integral is now in the standard form to which you can apply [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).